# Having trouble painting an html5 canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, background, onload

So I'm making a kind of game, and I'm just starting, so I'm doing what shows before you click it, but it's not working. Help would be much appreciated, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/holythunder/TXyaX/) a jsfiddle of my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few of issues I found:

- By looking at the code, I assume you wanted to use jQuery. You need to select that on the left, unfortunately for jsFiddle Mootools is the default
- Your onload event was called `Load` - need to have it lower case. Also, the event was called on the element - in jQuery, you just need to use `$(function() { ... })` and that function will be called then the page loaded, it's a shortcut
- To bind the event handler for click, you do `$(el).click`, not `$(el).onClick`. This is the same for all event handlers in general (you don't prepend "on" before)
- To get the element, you use `document.getElementById`, not just `getElementById`. This is the function on the `document` object, not a global function
- jQuery objects are not the same as "regular" DOM objects. When you do `document.getElementById`, you get a DOM object. You cannot call jQuery functions on that - you have to wrap it into a jQuery object before. To do that, you just do `$(canvas)`, where `canvas` is the variable holding the DOM element itself

Here's an updated jsFiddle that has canvas working basically:

- http://jsfiddle.net/TXyaX/4/

You would have to take a look at your functions (in `artisan` "namespace"), but you have the basic building block on jsFiddle working. You may also want to slim down the jsFiddle examples in the future - i.e. don't paste the whole HTML, just the relevant parts. Look at the left part of the jsFiddle screen - e.g. to add a script, don't put it into the HTML box, but use "Add Resource" on the left and put the URL of the .js file there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Woah, hell of an answer! Thanks alot mate, you've been really helpful.